# Why Dialog is not opened when button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have three dialogs which will be opened by clicking button...

I have linked both jquery-ui and jquery.min.js file and jquery-ui.css file...

But when i click the button it redirects to index page instead of opening dialog....

This is my jQuery code....

```
$(function(){
        $("#recipientDialogue").dialog({
          autoOpen:false,
        });
        $("#exclusionDialogue").dialog({
          autoOpen:false,
        });
        $("#suppressionDialogue").dialog({
          autoOpen:false,
        });

        $("openRecipient").click(function(){
           $("#recipientDialogue").dialog("open");
        });
    });
```

This is my html code...

```
    <td colspan="3"><button id="openRecipient">Choose Recipients</div></td>
          <td colspan="3"><button id="openSuppression">Choose Recipients</button></td>
          <td colspan="3"><button id="openExclusion">Choose Recipients</button></td>

<div id="recipientDialogue">
    <td colspan="3" style="padding-left: 55px;">
      <div id="recipientCheck"></div>
    </td>
</div>
<div id="suppressionDialogue">
    <td colspan="3" style="padding-left: 55px;"> 
      <div id="suppressionCheck"></div> 
    </td>
</div>
<div id="exclusionDialogue">
    <td colspan="3" style="padding-left: 55px;">
      <div id="exclusionCheck"></div>
    </td>
</div>
```

This is jquery code to populate checkboxes from static json array...

```
for(var i=0; i< encoded_recipient_array.length;i++){

        jQuery('<input/>', {type:'checkbox',
            value: encoded_recipient_array[i].id,
            name:'recipient_array[]'
            }).appendTo('#recipientCheck'); //append checkbox only with id as its value....
        jQuery('<p>',{'text':encoded_recipient_array[i].name
            }).appendTo('#recipientCheck'); //append label of checkbox ......
        jQuery('<br/>').appendTo('#recipientCheck'); //looks better you know...
    }
```

Any help?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid - you can't have `div` elements as a child of a `table`/`tbody`. Are your buttons in a `form` element? If so their default behaviour is to submit the form, hence it appears the page refreshes. Have you included jQuery first, before jQueryUI? Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: You seem to be missing the `#` in your jQuery selector: `$("#openRecipient").click(...)`.

Comment: Yes.. everything is in form tag...There is not any error on console...and jquery is before jquery-ui.... @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: Ok, first you need to fix the error with the `div` elements being incorrectly placed, then add `type="button"` to your `button` elements to stop them submitting the form

Comment: Thanks @Karin.. it solved... It is now displaying popup but it is refreshing page as soon as popup is displayed

Comment: Thank you @RoryMcCrossan... It solved everything... :)

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Comment: hey @RoryMcCrossan.. I have populated that dialog with checkboxes from jquery array... But now when i submit the form, there is error saying that undefined index recipient_array.... I am attaching that jquery code...

Comment: hey @Karin I have populated that dialog with checkboxes from jquery array... But now when i submit the form, there is error saying that undefined index recipient_array.... I am attaching that jquery code...

Answer (score 1):

You missed `#` to put before **openRecipient** button

```
$("#openRecipient").click(function(){ 
    $("#recipientDialogue").dialog("open");
});
```